# How can a completed match become a walkover?

Tags: rules, football, match-identification

During yesterday 2018 World Cup's match between Panama and Tunisia, a Polish-speaking sport commentator said that one of these countries (didn't hear exactly which one) had a football match with Cape Verde team which they lost and **which was later ruled out as a walkover**.

*How can an already played match, lost by one of teams, later be declared walkover?*

So far (up until yesterday) I was more than sure that a walkover can only happen when -- as name suggests -- one of the teams don't even show up to play the game.

Side question: About exactly which match Polish commentator was talking about?

Comment: Being a walkover has nothing to do with whether the match counts as legitimate or was played. What you're thinking of, is called a *default*.

Comment: It is quite likely that you are talking about a match in [2014 FIFA World Cup qualification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification_%E2%80%93_CAF_Second_Round). You can find more informatin *about this specific decision* in the linked Wikipedia article. The decision was related to [Fernando Varela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Varela_(Cape_Verdean_footballer)) playing for Cape Verde during his suspension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkover) on the term walkover suggests:

> A walkover is the awarding of a victory to a contestant because there
>   are no other contestants or the other contestants have been
>   **disqualified** or have **forfeited**.

So,

> How can an already played match, lost by one of teams, later be
>   declared walkover?

Easy, if it's later identified that a team fielded an ineligible player, or due to crowd violence, etc.

> Side question: About exactly which match Polish commentator was
>   talking about?

As [@Martin](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/how-can-a-completed-match-become-a-walkover#comment29396_18721) pointed out in the comments, most probably the commentator was referring to the [incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Varela_(Cape_Verdean_footballer)#International_career) of Fernando Varela playing for Cape Verde against Tunisia during his suspension.